# What verb to use to describe "a tucked hair returning to its original position"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Popped out? Sprung out? I can't find the correct word.

Example sentence:

> She tucked a strand of her chin-length hair behind her ear, only to __
>   again.

Comment: only for it to pop out again -- works for me.

Comment: *... only for it to spring back....*, if her hair's curly, sounds good to me.

Comment: Wait..what's the word for probably the more likely situation, which is for it to move of of its original position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> She tucked a **lock** of her chin-length hair behind her ear, only for it to **flop** again.

Oxford *Living* Dictionaries gives this definition of the verb

> **[flop](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flop)**
>   [*with adverbial*] Fall, move, or hang in a loose and ungainly way.
>
> - ‘his blond hair flopped over his eyes’
> - ‘Some of his dark hair flopped onto his forehead and I almost reached out to tuck it back into place.’

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a special word, but "fall out" would be one of the most natural ways. Definitely not pop or sprung though.

One thing though; I would change the phrasing slightly and say:

> ...only **for it** to fall out again.

Comment: Thumbs down.  Hair falling out generally means it's getting detached from your head.

Comment: @aparente001 No - context matters. Just saying your hair falls out of course implies that you lose it, but in this sentence and as I phrased it ("only for it to fall out again") would be an appropriate usage and understood as intended

Comment: I would agree with you if the sentence went like this: *She tucked a stray strand of hair back into the bun at the back of her head, only for it to fall out again.*  But to me, "She tucked a strand of her chin-length hair behind her ear, only for it to fall out again" sounds weird.  Fall out of what?  I suppose, since the hair was only pushed behind the ear, it could *fall forward*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how poetic you want to be, you could say:

> She tucked a strand of her chin-length hair behind her ear, only to have it emerge again.

(Or you could use @BennyLewis' phrasing and go with *...only for it to emerge again.*)

Less poetic would be:

> ...only for it to **come loose** again.

Any which way, hair is a pain.  (says the guy who hasn't had a haircut in 7 or 8 years.)

Answer (score 0):

You *do* your hair (into a hairdo) by arranging it. When it becomes disarranged, we can say it comes (or becomes) undone.

> She tucked a strand of her chin-length hair behind her ear, only to **come undone** again.

*Do* can mean to set or style the hair or makeup. (The Free Dictionary #6). A couple of years ago, *[the undone look](http://glamradar.com/how-to-get-the-undone-look/)* became a fashionable way to style one's hair and dress.